# Generate HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to generate some HTML using jQuery, I want to just create the elements with the required classes etc, and then append them to each other if that makes sense. I have written the below code, it doesn't produce any errors but also isn't adding the HTML to container at all.

What's wrong?

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.twitter_plugin = function( options ) {

    var container = this[0];

    console.log('Started');
    // Make aJax call

    // Generate HTML
    $con = $("<div>", { "class" : "tweet" });
    $(container).append($con);
      $col1 = $("<div>", { "class" : "twocol" });
      $con.append($col1);
      $col2 = $("<div>", { "class" : "tencol last" });
      $con.append($col2);

        // Profile Image
        $tweet_profile_div = $("<div>", { "class" : "tweet-profile-photo" });
        $col1.append($tweet_profile_div);
          $profile_img = $("img", { "src" : '', "class" : "responsive-img" });
          $tweet_profile_div.append($profile_img);
        // END Profile Image

      // Tweet
      $tweet_head = $("div", { "class" : "tweet-head" });
      // END Tweet

  };
}(jQuery));
```

Executing this like so:

```
<script src="js-src/themev2/twitter_plugin.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#map_canvas").twitter_plugin({ });
});
</script>
```

**Edit 1**

@Sean Reimer, my twitter_plugin function is being executed without that change you suggested, as the console.log is displayed, so this isn't the issue

Comment: Do you get your console log?

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have an IIFE for jquery, but within you have your  '$.fn.twitter_plugin function' defined but not called.
At the end of your function definition you should add () to  invoke it as well.

so

```
      $tweet_head = $("div", { "class" : "tweet-head" });
      // END Tweet
  };
```

should be

```
      $tweet_head = $("div", { "class" : "tweet-head" });
      // END Tweet

  }();
```

I also am not sure if this[0] is entirely reliable it might be better to just save the body as your container element. This is just a window object, so it doesn't have a 0 index element

`var container = $('body')`
would solve your problems.

Comment: `this[0]` gets the element defined from here `$("#map_canvas").twitter_plugin({ });` as i need to put the new elements in there, not in the body. And thanks for the answer to my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake I made, code works fine, I simply misspelt the ID for the target element, this works now.